# Why does a user get updated using Spring Security and Grails without calling save()?

Tags: grails, spring-security

Overview:

- User, UserRole and Role are pretty much the standard model from
  SpringSecurity plugin in grails
- One thing that I ensure (in the controller) is that there is only 1 role per user
- There are 3 roles created in my bootstrap: Admin, Manager and User

  - Admins can do all actions
  - Manager can update other managers and users
  - Users can only update themselves (but not their roles)

In my controller I use annotations to generally control most of the security but for the update and save actions I add the logic for more advance checking:

```
@Transactional
def update(User userInstance) {
    User currentUser = User.get(springSecurityService.currentUser?.id)
    Role currentRole = currentUser.getAuthorities().getAt(0)    // There is only 1 role per user, so give the first

    Role roleInstance = Role.get(params['role.id'])

    // SECURITY LOGIC -> Move to service
    if (currentRole.authority.equals("ROLE_USER")) {

        if (userInstance != currentUser || !roleInstance.authority.equals("ROLE_USER")) {
            notAllowed(userInstance)
            return
        }
    } else if (currentRole.authority.equals('ROLE_MANAGER')) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    // REST OF CODE - User is saved here
}
```

Now here is where I get a weird problem. If I log in as a ROLE_USER and update an ROLE_ADMIN I get the notAllowed error message as I should and the action returns right after so it doesn't continue to the REST OF CODE where the User is actually saved.

If I look at the admin it actually has been updated (persisted). Why is this the case since it never got to the save() call?

Thanks!

Comment: your rest of the code(//REST OF CODE - User is saved here) is getting executed , put it in else block and then try . I'm pretty sure code for save is running even after notAllowed is called and return.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati No it doesn't hit REST OF CODE, I've ran the debugger and verified. See Burt's answer below as to why it saves regardless if the save is called.

Comment: yes! It's the right answer in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spring Security - it's just a coincidence that it's happening when working with domain classes that are used by the plugin.

By default Grails uses the "open session in view" pattern, which is common when using Hibernate. At the beginning of each request a Hibernate Session is created and stored in a ThreadLocal and the persistence code uses that if it's available, and at the end of the request the session is flushed and closed.

This is particularly helpful when working with lazy-loaded instances and collections. If there isn't an existing Hibernate Session available, the persistence code creates one and uses it to retrieve instances from the database, but since it created the session, it closes it after the query finishes. This leaves the instances disconnected from any session and there's no auto-reattach logic, so if you attempt to access a non-initialized lazy-loaded instance or collection after the object is disconnected you get an exception. But if there was an open session already, the persistence code uses it but doesn't close it, so loaded instances are attached and lazy loading will work.

What you're seeing is Hibernate detecting that a persistent instance has been modified, and by default when the session is closed it will detect the changes and helpfully flush them to the database for you. This happens with or without a `save()` call, so in effect the only time you typically need to call `save()` is when inserting new instances.

You can disable the open session in view support, but you lose a lot by doing this and it's in general not a good idea. You can also customize how it works, when flushing happens, etc. But in general you should disconnect attached instances that you don't want to be auto-flushed. There's a GORM method for that - `discard()` - and if you call it on a modified instance Hibernate won't be aware of it when the flush happens and nothing will be saved.

Unrelated - this line

```
User currentUser = User.get(springSecurityService.currentUser?.id)
```

should just be

```
User currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
```

since the `getCurrentUser()` method retrieves the User instance from the database using the cached id from the security authentication. You're using that User instance to get its id and then throwing it away, and using the id to load the same User again.

Comment: Thank you Burt! Learning Grails is learning many technologies! Also thank you for the catch on the currentUser!

Comment: @Burt Beckwith. How can we disable open session?

Comment: As a side note, the discard() must happen before notAllowed() call not after it. The notAllowed() method is pretty much like the standard notFound() method. Again thank Burt for explaining it all out!