# Curious call of merge inside un-true if case

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm

If `sample` is **not** `null` the line with `merge(..)` is called while the other 5 lines in the `if` are not. Why the ****? I'm jumping out the window soon...

```
class SampleService {
    def markError(def job, def prop) {
        def sample = job.getSamples().find { sample ->
             sample.getProp() == prop }
        if (sample == null) {
            log.debug("i can see this only when sample == null")
            println "i can see this only when sample == null"
            def newSample = new Sample(prop: prob)
            newSample.setJob(job)
            newSample.merge(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        }
    }
}
```

I did already:

- grails clean & grails compile.
- deleted target folder and bin folder.
- restarted app several times.
- checked with intellij and eclipse.

Comment: My be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731497/why-does-a-user-get-updated-using-spring-security-and-grails-without-calling-sav?noredirect=1#comment57236079_34731497 could help. Here `What you're seeing is Hibernate detecting that a persistent instance has been modified, and by default when the session is closed it will detect the changes and helpfully flush them to the database for you.`  makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was missguided by the debuggers: The line has not been executed but highlighted. I don't know why it has been highlighted.

Hope this prevents anyone else from going crazy! :)